# Conflict between on click events

Tags: jquery

Hello guys I'm having a bad time trying to solve a conflict between two onclick events. My project has a canvas and a properties box.

I can add elements(pressing a button) to canvas by appending them to It (These elements have the class '.element' and they are divs, and the canvas is also a div element).

So, once I have an element on canvas, I can see It's properties (on the properties box) by clicking on It. To handle this click event I implemented the following function:

```
var canvas = $('#canvas');

 $(function(){
    canvas.delegate('.element','click', function(){
    // Here I update the properties box with information of the clicked element
    // and and some css to the element so user can know that It's selected
    });
 });
```

Now I want to implement a function that when I click elsewhere on the canvas, It clears the property box (once no element is selected). I tried doing this:

```
$(function(){
  canvas.on('click',function(){
         //Clear properties box here
  });
});
```

But now It cancels the first function (It's like only the second one is executed). Do you guys know how can I turn this situation around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the event as an argument to the binding of the first function, and try adding [`#stopPropagation`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```
canvas.on('click', '.element', function(e){
  // all your code here
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

what's happening here is that by click the `.element` div, you trigger the first function, but because the `.element` is contained within the canvas, you're also triggering the second binding (which clears the box). stopPropagation prevents the event from bubbling up to any parent divs which will prevent you from triggering the second binding.
also, I'd recommend changing the way you're delegating (to how I've written it) because the `#delegate` method is deprecated.